# How to send data as a string from NodeJs runtime to Arduino board using Serial communication?

Tags: node.js, string, arduino, serial-port, led

I am working in a project that requires serial communication between Arduino  board and NodeJs runtime in Raspberry Pi.

I want to send a string like "255,100,100,255" from NodeJs program inside my Pi to Arduino board to control the brightness of 4 lights. 4 elements inside the string are the brightness of each light.

How to code in both NodeJs and Arduino program so that Arduino board receive all the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the module [serialport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport).

First install it using

> `npm i serialport`

Then in your NodeJS code you can create a sender:

```
let serial = require("serialport").SerialPort;
let sp = new serial("/dev/ttyACM0", { baudrate: 9600 });
sp.on("open", function(){
    sp.write("255,100,100,255", function(err, res) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
    });
});
```

While on your arduino you can make a receiver:

```
int incomingByte = 0;
void setup(){ Serial.begin(9600); }
void loop(){
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        incomingByte = Serial.read();
        Serial.println(incomingByte);
    }
}
```